# uneditable layout block in Pages.app

Tags: pages, formatting

I have a Pages document with two layout blocks that cannot be resized. The top one especially, is very narrow, extending from 2.5cm (on the left) to 13.4cm (on the right). The document itself is 21 cm wide and has 1 cm margins.

There is no way I can push my text further right than 13.4 cm. How should I proceed?

I have this very small Pages document exhibiting the issues, which I will
The document was originally imported from a .docx file. This may explain how the problem cam to happen. It doesn't explain why Pages now has a layout structure that's completely impossible to edit by the user. Edit: this document was created with Pages for Mac version 10.1(6913).

I may miss something, but I just spent 1 hour on the phone sharing my screen with a level 2 Apple support person, who failed to help, and basically advised me to use MS Word.

URL of this writable document:

https://www.icloud.com/pages/02EIFENQPkpOgBZWY-Bn6lMEw#Pages_layout_issue

In case of vandalism, I put a read only version of this document at:

https://www.icloud.com/pages/0SfFPGvoWh_hlS9GLtMDC8tZg#Pages_layout_issue_original

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: With which Pages version has this document been created?

Comment: this was created with version 10.1 (6913), the latest version at the time I posted

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, b/c, well … life. Unfortunately, no luck. I honestly don't remember if the "old" Pages versions (up to '09) supported this (I think they did), but the current Pages does not. While you apparently can see the text, editing is a no. You can try opening the document in Pages '09 if you have it at hand somewhere or indeed use Word. Or use a floating text box to replicate the functionality in Pages 10.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually, the only solution I found for this is to copy and paste-without-format into a layout area that doesn't exhibit the problem.